# PhpStorm Live Template plugin conflict

Tags: php, templates, phpstorm, expand

I'm trying to use the PhpStorm Live Templates, but they are not working. I think it must be a plugin I installed, but I removed them and it still does not work.

I am on a PHP file and I tried using `pubf` for the public function, and it expands something else.

Does anyone know what that red circle with de initials FX on the popup mean? Does anyone know how to deactivate it?

[image]

Comment: *"Does anyone know what that red circle with de initials FX on the popup mean?"* That means that the completion entry is a function.

Comment: 1) If you create your own Live Template for PHP context -- will it work? 2) Maybe you have disabled them somehow? 3) if you think it's a plugin that disabled them ... try disabling all non-bundled-by-default plugins and see if it will make any better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Live Templates, I changed the php templates I want to use or create to be 'Aplicable to PHP, the general option. It worked.